# IDE/PATA wire order?

Tags: cable, pata

I know the red wire is Pin 1, is the next wire (to the right in picture) Pin 2 or 3? Basically wondering if it alternates? I am honestly hacking up a IDE cable to connect an AC '97 connector (10-pin) to raw headphone/microphone wires on the front of a my custom PC

[image: IDE Pin Out]

Comment: I understand the pin order, I don't understand the wire order

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your IDE/PATA cable pinout looks like this :

[image]

The pins following " pin 1 " row are uneven (1, 3, 5, 7, and so on...)

The pins on the bottom row are the oposite (2, 4, 6, 8, and so on...)

(Note : pin 20 is blocked from the cable)

The ribbon cable pinout of the connector is simple. If you count from the red wire to the last gray wire, it goes normal : *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ......., 39, 40*
[image]

Comment: I'll be verifying this in the next few days. Just thought how I could use a voltmeter to test your theory is correct!

Answer (score 4):

The name of the connector is IDC, for Insulation Displacement Connector, and the wires are ribbon cable.  The wires of ribbon cable are numbered sequentially, and are mapped one-to-one to the pin numbers of the IDC (i.e. wire 1 goes to pin 1, wire 2 to pin 2, etc).

> is the next wire (to the right in picture) Pin 2 or 3?

The wire for Pin 2 would be adjacent to Pin 1.

> Basically wondering if it alternates?

No, the wire numbering for a ribbon cable is sequential. The IDC is designed to match that numbering.